# GWTTestCase gave me an error

Tags: java, gwt, testing

I write simple test using GWTTestCase, here is:

```
public class SampleTest extends GWTTestCase {

    @Override
    public String getModuleName() {
        return "path.to.my.one.and.only.Module";
    }

    public void testSome() {
        assertNotNull(null);
    }
}
```

But when I run **mvn test**, the test failed with next error:

```
[ERROR] Unable to find type 'java.lang.Object'
   [ERROR] Hint: Check that your module inherits 'com.google.gwt.core.Core' either directly or indirectly (most often by inheriting module 'com.google.gwt.user.User')
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.648 sec <<< FAILURE!
```

I have 'com.google.gwt.user.User' in my module.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you need to inherit `com.google.gwt.core.Core` in your `gwt.xml` file and it is not saying that your class should extend/implement it.

As you have not provided `gwt.xml`. I am giving an example.

Give this a try in your gwt.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE 
    module 
    PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.3.0//EN" 
    "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.3.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">

<module rename-to="hello">
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.core.Core" />
    <source path="foo" /> <!-- Your package name -->
</module>
```

Comment: Yes I understand, like I said I have exactly this module inherited in My.gwt.xml module.

Comment: The problem was in name of the class, it must begin with "GwtTest". So I change name of the class to GwtTestSampleTest. Next issue was that I must run **mvn gwt:test** instead of **mvn test**

Comment: Post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by *fixing my JRE definitions*, to do that go to **Window** > **Preferences** > **Java** > **Installed JREs** > **Add your JRE's correct path.** And there you go!